# Git - Prevent merge commits to master repository

Tags: git, svn

We are transitioning from SVN to Git. As part of the process we want to have a Git mirror set up that everyone works off of that a script then dcommits to the current SVN master. The issue is:

- Someone accidentally does a merge instead of a rebase locally.
- They push to the master git repository. While Fst-Foward-Only is turned on this does not prevent merges.
- The script tries to push to SVN and is not allowed since SVN does not understand the merged commits.

In our master Git pre-commit hook how can we check if the pushed commit is a merge and reject it?

Comment: You may want to start with `git rev-parse <hash>^@`, which shows all parents of `<hash>`. Merge commits have more than one parent; non-merge commits have a single parent.

Comment: What are you using for the central repo? Gerrit, for example, lets you restrict who can push a merge-commit. It has to be done with a server side hook. Pull the source for Gerrit and see how they do it, would be the simplest solution.

Comment: how come you guys are doing comments instead of responses so I can upvote??